# Comment Line in tmLanguage starts with .* TextMate Grammar Syntax Highlight

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, vscode-extensions, tmlanguage

I am working on my own Syntax Highlighting extension for VS code and I have comment lines that start with ".*" which I want to highlight.

For code I have:

```
"comment": {
    "patterns": [{
        "name": "comment.line.as",
        "match":  "(\.\*).*$\n?",
        "captures": {
            '1': {
                "name": "punctuation.definition.comment.as"
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

But this does not seems to add the correct comment scope to my lines that begin with .*.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Let me try to rephrase:
The comment lines are not being highlighted at all as comment lines. I think i have an error in the TextMate syntax because I believe the regex is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple mistake, since this is in a .json file and the regex is in between quotes I have to escape the escape characters.
. become \.
* become \* 
etc...